# Best practices for deactivating a Salesforce User without losing any data?

Tags: user-management, deactivate, mass-action

I haven't found an easy way to do this. I need to deactivate a Salesforce user, but first I need to know ALL the records, all the flows, jobs, reports, dashboards, etc the user owns so I can transfer the ownership to an existing user in the org.

I want to document best practices and ways for doing this.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first Freeze the user, attempt to Deactivate, then follow the links for everywhere the user is listed as required. Aside from that, you could also conceptually download your org's metadata with [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) or another tool, then scan the local files for the user's username or ID (some metadata refer to users either way). This would also provide you with a quick way to deploy the changes to all the metadata at once.

Comment: Thank you. I'll explore the Metadata road !!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the question so bad I'm getting negative votes? Haven't found any simple explanation around the internet.

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre I suppose it might be based on our typical "opinion-based" question, although they didn't CV that way, so I don't know for sure.